# How to set AWS Cognito Tokens in localstorage

Tags: javascript, amazon-cognito

I am implementing SSO Authentication with AWS Cognito, Now I am able to successfully login a user and retrieve id_token, access_token, refresh_tokens..., and redirect the user to home page, So my happy flow is working fine,

Issue I am facing is when when ever a user is redirected to login page I check if any available session for the user with help of getCurrentUser(). Now when I login user with simple username and password I use

```
var cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);    
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(...)
```

Here I know after successful authentication token key are stored in my local-storage by aws-sdk. and these same keys are used by getCurrentUser method to fetch current user session.

Same I am not able to do in my Oauth apporach. I get the code in the query parameter and make a post call to fetch tokens. Now how to set the same token in my local storage to implement retrieveSession functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The cognito sdk is specific to aws and is not a general purpose oauth sdk. Also note that this sdk (https://github.com/amazon-archives/amazon-cognito-identity-js) is now deprecated in favour of aws amplify js (https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js).

If you want to use OAuth and openId connect approach, I would recommend to use oidc-client-js (https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js).